# Can I pause itertools on python, and resume later?

Tags: python, performance, permutation, python-itertools

I need to create a list of strings with all the possible combinations of all letters uppercase and lowercase, with non repeating characters, of lenght 14, this is massive and I know it will take a lot of time and space.
My code right now is this:

```
import itertools

filename = open("strings.txt", "w")

for com in itertools.permutations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 14):
    filename.write("\n"+"1_"+"".join(com)+"\n"+"0_"+"".join(com))
    print ("".join(com))
```

pretty basic, it does the job and I have not found a faster way as of yet (tried a java algorithm I found that seemed faster but python was faster)
Since this will take a long time, from time to time I need to turn off my computer, so I need to be able to save somewhere where I left and continue, else I will start from the beginning each time it crashes/turn off my pc / anything happen.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Why do you need to compute all these permutations? What will you do next?

Comment: Writing to a file every iteration is slow, I would suggest writing to the file periodically, for example every 1000 or 10000 iterations.

Comment: Um, I'm not sure you actually appreciate how long this will take. There are about 1.54x10^23 permutations. Even if each iteration took only 1 nanosecond (it takes significantly longer than that) it would *still* require 1.54x10^14 seconds which is [about 5 million years](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2852%21%2F%2852-14%29%21%29+Nanoseconds)

Comment: And the output file would be around [5 thousand million Peta Bytes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%2852%21%2F%2852-14%29%21%29+*+34+bytes+to+petabytes).

Comment: I know all of that. I will make more restrictions to make it less painful, but I didn't ask if this was practical, viability, etc, I asked for pause lol

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) that iterator object. Its internal state will be stored in the pickle file. When you resume it should start from where it left off.

Something like this:

```
import itertools
import os
import pickle
import time

# if the iterator was saved, load it
if os.path.exists('saved_iter.pkl'):
    with open('saved_iter.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        iterator = pickle.load(f)
# otherwise recreate it
else:
    iterator = itertools.permutations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 14)

try:
    for com in iterator:
        # process the object from the iterator
        print(com)
        time.sleep(1.0)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # if the script is about to exit, save the iterator state
    with open('saved_iter.pkl', 'wb') as f:
        pickle.dump(iterator, f)
```

Which results in:

```
>python so_test.py
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'o')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'p')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'q')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'r')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 's')

>python so_test.py
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 't')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'u')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'v')
('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'w')
```

Comment: He should also use the append option `"a"` when opening the file `"strings.txt"`, otherwise the previous results will be overwritten.

Comment: For that "strings.txt" file, yes. I omitted that from the answer for simplicity.

Comment: This looks interesting! Thank you! and yeah, I figured I should change the mode to append after a pause